# Find the sender of the `destroyed (QObject*)` signal

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I am currently wondering how to reasonably use the `QObject::destroyed(QObject*)` [signal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#destroyed).

## An observation

I noticed that `QWidget`-derived objects are treated slightly different. Consider the following small self-contained and compiling example:

```
/* sscce.pro:
QT += core gui widgets
CONFIG += c++11
TARGET = sscce
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
*/

#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QtDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton;
    QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::destroyed,
        [=](QObject *o) { qDebug() << o; });

    delete button;

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer;
    QObject::connect(timer, &QTimer::destroyed,
        [=](QObject *o) { qDebug() << o; });

    delete timer;

    return app.exec();
}
```

This is its output:

```
QWidget(0x1e9e1e0)
QObject(0x1e5c530)
```

So presumably, the signal is emitted from `QObject`'s d-tor, so only the `QObject` base remains when the slot is called for the `QTimer`. However, `QWidget`'s d-tor seems to intercept as it still identifies itself as a `QWidget` from the slot.

## And the problem

Let's assume we have a timer pool that organizes a couple of timers in a `QList<QTimer *>`:

```
struct Pool {
    QTimer *getTimer() {
        return timers.at(/* some clever logic here */);
    }        

    QList<QTimer *> timers;
};
```

Now an incautious user might delete the timer that was borrowed to him/her. Well, we can react, and simply remove that timer from the list. A slot will do the trick:

```
Pool::Pool() {
    /* for each timer created */
    connect(theTimer, SIGNAL(destroyed(QObject*),
        this, SLOT(timerDestroyed(QObject*));
}

void Pool::timerDeleted(QObject *object) {
    QTimer *theTimer = /* hrm. */
    timers.removeOne(theTimer);
}
```

But what now? Hrm. When the slot is called, the `QTimer` already is in destruction and partially destroyed - only its `QObject` base remains. So I objously cannot `qobject_cast<QTimer *>(object)`.

To resolve this issue, I could think of the following tricks:

1. Store `QObject`s in the list. Then I'd have to downcast every time I use an item from the list. This could be done using `static_cast`, though, as I know there will only be `QTimer`s in the list, so no need for `dynamic_cast` or `qobject_cast`.
2. Insteat of `removeOne` traverse the list using an `iterator` and then compare each `QTimer` item directly to the `QObject`. Then use `QList::erase` or such.
3. `static_cast` or even `reinterpret_cast` the `QObject` to a `Qtimer` nonetheless.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for tricks, you could simply use the base QObject objectName and remove the destroyed timer based on that.

Comment: That would require an objectName to be actually set, of course. But then I'd end up traversing the list, so I could as well just compare the pointers I suppose. Or hide the traversal in QObject::findChild(), which does similar.

Comment: You made an important implication I was not really aware of, though: The destroyed() signal is emitted from the QObject d-tor, so at least the QObject base still is perfectly alive and usable.

Comment: Right.  It's kind of a hack but I've done it before for various QWidgets.  Setting the objectName isn't too big of a deal if your data structures are set up for it.

Comment: I probably even don't need to. A static_cast is just some pointer aligning magic, without ever accessing the pointed-to object (unlike dynamic/qobject_cast), so it should be fine to just cast and then compare the pointers directly. Will do some research on this, though.

Answer (score 1):

It seems clear that your problem is one of object ownership; in particular, how to convey who is responsible for destroying an object. If your Pool object *owns* the QTimer objects (and thus the user should not `delete` them), make it clear through the interface, for example returning a `QTimer&` instead of a `QTimer*` from your getTimer method. I'm not really well versed in Qt, but if you actually wanted to *transmit ownership* of the object returned from a method and thus make the user responsible of its deletion, you'd likely return a `std::unique_ptr<QTimer>`.

Comment: There are a couple of ownership patterns in Qt. Transferring ownership usually involves some kind of, like *takeFoo()*. Yet, returning a reference is unpractical here as QTimer is polymorphic and one would end up taking the returned reference's address anyway...

Comment: But I think there is trouble in ownership policies with the Qt API, +1.

Comment: But if you are worried about polymorphism, a `QTimer&` is just as polymorphic as a `QTimer*`. It is just returning by value which you do not want. Besides, if you really need it, you can then take the address of the returned reference, which gives you the address of the referred-to object (there is no such thing as the address of a reference), which was your original `QTimer*`. This would cost you just one additional character (&) in user code, and the fact that the ownership is retained by the Pool is conveyed clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a direct cast:

```
void Pool::timerDeleted(QObject *object) {
    QTimer *theTimer = (QTimer*)object; //qobject_cast doesn't work here
//we are sure that only a timer can be a sender
    timers.removeOne(theTimer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could base your list on [QPointer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpointer.html) instead of raw pointers. I.e. write

```
QList<QPointer<QTimer>> timers;
```

Now when one of the timers in the list goes away, the corresponding entry in the list will automagically be cleared. It will *not* be removed, though! But when you access the timer via your `getTimer()` method, an entry whose timer has been deleted will now return a `nullptr` (and not a dangling pointer).

And yes, `QWidget` emits `destroyed()` in its own destructor. This is why you see a real `QWidget` in that case. Everybody else uses `QObject`'s implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The other way around is safe. Cast `QTimer *` to `QObject *` instead:

```
void Pool::timerDeleted(QObject *object) {
    const auto it = std::find_if(timers.begin(), timers.end(), [object](QTimer *timer) {
        return static_cast<QObject *>(timer) == object;
    });
    Q_ASSERT(it != timers.end());
    timers.erase(it);
}
```

Or use [erase_if(QList &list, Predicate pred)](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qlist.html#erase_if) introduced in Qt 6.1.